# Only positive/negative numbers in subintervals.

Tags: calculus

Given the interval $[-1,1]$, can I define a partition $P_n$ so that in every subinterval of the partition  there will be only positive numbers(including $0$), or only negative numbers?

Comment: Erm.. How can there be negative numbers in the interval $[0,1]$?

Comment: @yoyostein Oh god, $[-1,1]$

Comment: Consider any partition $P_n$ such that $0\in P_n.$

Comment: @mfl I can't see how this is related.

Comment: If $P_n=\{a_0=-1,a_1,\cdots,a_k= 0,\cdots, a_n=1\}$ every interval $[a_i,a_{i+1}]$ contains only non-negative or non-positive numbers. Why? Because $a_i$ and $a_{i+1}$ have the same sign or one of them is zero.

Comment: @mfl Just to make sure I got this right.. $P_1 = [a_1, a_2], P_2 = [a_2, a_3]...$ and \Delta{x}=2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A partition is defined as a set of $n$ points, $-1=a_1<a_2<\cdots< a_n=1$.

If, for some $k$, $a_k=0$, then for $i\leq k$, the intervals $(a_{i-1}, a_i)$ contain only negative numbers, while for $i> k$, they contain only positive numbers. So, the answer is yes.

However, if you are looking at *closed* intervals, clearly, the answer must be no. This is because $0$ can either be one of the dividing points (in which case $[a_k, 0]$ contains $0$ and a negative number) or not (in which case $0$ is an internal point of an interval which contains $\epsilon$ and $-\epsilon$ for some small $\epsilon>0$).

Comment: @xum: Usually the sub-intervals of a partition are closed. Or not?

Comment: @EmilioNovati See my edit.